# How Handle Error from API request flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I want to handle http request flutter with some error message and show it to user on screen but I cannot do that . I just make it based on the suggestion but it didn't work for me. Please, anyone, help me Here is my function to call API.

API response :

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "message": "this box is not valid !!",
    "data": [],
    "error": [],
    "status": 400
}
```

and this is the funtion :

```
  Future<BoxModel> addBox(String boxName, String boxIdentifiant,
      String adress_circulation, String proprietaire) async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = localStorage.getString('access_token');
    await checkInternet();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };
    Map<String, String> body = {
      'boxName': boxName,
      'boxIdentifiant': boxIdentifiant,
      'adress_circulation': adress_circulation,
      'proprietaire': proprietaire,
    };
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ApiUtil.ADD_BOX),
        headers: headers, body: jsonEncode(body));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var data = body['message'];
      BoxModel box = BoxModel.fromJson(body);
      return box;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to add box');
    }
    
  }

void addBox() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      String boxName = _boxNameController.text;
      String boxIdentifiant = _boxIdentifiantController.text;
      String adress_circulation = _adress_circulationController.text;
      String proprietaire = _proprietaireController.text;
      BoxModel box = await boxApi.addBox(
          boxName, boxIdentifiant, adress_circulation, proprietaire);
      if (box != null) {
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BoxSettings()));
      }
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
  }
```

how i can to show the message error on the screen ?

Comment: Where do you want to show the error message ?

Comment: on the screen (for user) . @Nisanth Reddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
var data = body['message'];
BoxModel box = BoxModel.fromJson(body);
return box;
```

to

```
var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
if(body['error'].isNotEmpty || body['status'] != 200) {
    // make error boolean variable true and set in view if true show error message.
} else {
   // make error boolean variable false
   var data = body['message'];
   BoxModel box = BoxModel.fromJson(body);
   return box;
}
```

Comment: // make error boolean variable true and set in view if true show error message. ??? @Saied Islam Shuvo

Comment: Declare a Boolean variable if there was error make variable true and not then false. In widget check it true or false, if true show error message if not then show rest of the widget

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using a `SnackBar` you can change your code to show the error in the `SnackBar` itself.

You can change your code to this,

```
boxApi.addBox(boxName, boxIdentifiant, adress_circulation, proprietaire)
  .then((box) {
    if (box != null)
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BoxSettings()));
  }).catchError((error) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("this box is not valid !!")));
  });
```

Comment: yes it's works but i would like to display  "message": "this box is not valid !!" instead of "Exception : failed to add box .@Nisanth Reddy

Comment: Updated my answer. Whatever your provide inside `SnackBar(content: Text( ... )))` will be visible on the screen. Does that work for you ?

Comment: yes it's work . the main thing is how i can display any error message automatically  from api on screen @Nisanth Reddy

Comment: To handle any error from `any` api, you would need one main class at the root of your `Widget` tree and only call it's function to use apis. This is how `Navigator` api also works since `Navigator` is at the root of your application. Once you make your own root widget, something like `NetworkWidget` and handle calling apis inside of that widget's code, then you can write code inside that single widget to handle errors and show it on the screen. This is a bit complex but achievable.

Comment: do you have an example ? @Nisanth Reddy

Comment: This is hard to explain in a comment. You need to write a full fledged class to handle all situation. This is generally unnecessary since flutter already provides callback and you easily call `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar` from anywhere like I have shown in my answer. Even the other answer requires you to store in state and then use it which already makes it unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Thanks for accepting the answer. If you reaaaally want that kind of a root widget, ask another question. I will try to write it, but it's not going to be easy. There would be maany things to handle. So much headache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232564/discussion-between-lucky-and-nisanth-reddy).